# Is it a bug in android input method editor/soft keyboard

Tags: android

Please watch the video provided , i couldn't explain it well in text

[this is the video](https://youtu.be/G3s4bdULX7s)

Here in the edittext i have `inputType="number"` attribute which allows only digits 0-9 to enter but if i press any other character other then digits and then press a digit it gets entered but when i press next digit then the previously entered digits is inputted again.

Is it a bug in android itself , can i don't something to prevent it from happening

I am using Oreo

Comment: do you have a TextWatcher, a TextChangedListener or something like that setup on this EditText?

Comment: @muetzenflo no it is simple Edittext, it just gets a default text 500, but removed it as you can see in the video, i just changed input type today, then i noticed this phenomena

Comment: hmm then it is indeed very strange. Does the same error happen on a real device? I heard that this kind of behavior may only happen on an emulator.

Comment: @muetzenflo that was a real honor device running oreo i recorded screen, i didn't test on any other device though.

Comment: @muetzenflo when firstly i entered 588 it didn't happen , it happens only when i press special character then two digits, in special characters it is not happening with @ and # , also not happening with alphabets

Comment: hmm then I am sorry...cant help you there. You could try setting the inputtype to `android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"`, but I dont think this will help.